# Calculate substring that fits into a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` which needs to be square in some cases and the text that goes in the `UILabel` might not necessarily fit into the square `UILabel` and for that very reason I need to calculate the amount of text that would fit into the frame of the `UILabel`. I am using this piece of code to get the index of the string, the substring to which would fit into the UILabel -

```
CGFloat labelWidth     = self.textLabel.frame.size.width;
CGFloat labelHeight    = self.textLabel.frame.size.height - titleRect.size.height - 16.0;
CGSize  sizeConstraint = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : font};

CGRect boundingRect = [body boundingRectWithSize:sizeConstraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];
if (boundingRect.size.height > labelHeight)
{
    NSUInteger stringIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger prev;
    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    do
    {
        prev = stringIndex;
        if (mode == NSLineBreakByCharWrapping)
            stringIndex++;
        else
            stringIndex = [body rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet options:0 range:NSMakeRange(stringIndex + 1, [body length] - stringIndex - 1)].location;
    }

    while (stringIndex != NSNotFound && stringIndex < [body length] && [[body substringToIndex:stringIndex] boundingRectWithSize:sizeConstraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil].size.height <= labelHeight);

    return prev;
}
```

The substring I get using this index is far too big and goes out of the frame of the `UILabel`

Anything I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I am trying to use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` as suggested by @rmaddy but the `UILabel` which is inside a `UIScrollView` is refusing to stick to it's frame. Here is the code -

```
self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.width);
[self setText:self.titleText andBody:self.bodyText andFontName:fontname andSize:size andColor:self.color];
```

I imagine setting the text in the `UILabel` is making it adjust its height. I have tried setting the text before setting the frame but it doesn't work either. I've been stuck in this too long now.

Comment: Why go to the trouble. Just set the label's `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`.

Comment: @rmaddy never came to my mind. Let me try that and see if that fulfils my demands

Comment: @rmaddy what would I get if logged the text of the textLabel? The whole string or the truncated string? I am asking this because I also need the truncated string.

Comment: Try it, see what you get.

Comment: Umm, I am getting the full string. But I am rechecking the code which sets the frame of the UILabel. The UILabel is supposed to expand in some cases and stay square in some so it's got a little complicated in there

Comment: @rmaddy The UILabel is inside a UIScrollView if you think that would make a difference. I think it is because I can't get the textLabel to stick to square frame. Is there anywhere we an have a quick chat if that's not too much to ask?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check the length of the string and adapt it to the label width.

Something like this:

```
CGSize sizeOfText = [self.label.text boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(self.label.intrinsicContentSize.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                             options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                          attributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.label.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName] context: nil].size;

if (self.label.intrinsicContentSize.height < ceilf(sizeOfText.height)) {
// label is truncated
// so do something here
}else{
// in here do something else
}
```